# Representing a digital ramp function in terms of unit step function

Tags: discrete-signals, unit-shift

I am following a DSP course by Prof. Datta Roy which is available on you-tube. I have a concern on one of the ways he represents a digital ramp function in-terms of digital step functions. The digital step function is defined as:

[image]

A ramp function can be drawn a follows.  $X(n)$:

[image]

It is represented on the lecture (He performs this representation at https://youtu.be/JpHXMcDxNiA?list=PL9567DFCA3A66F299&t=382) in-terms of digital step functions as: $x(n) = n[u(n) - u(n-4)]$.I would argue this may be wrong. When n=1, if we use this equation and just substitute illustratively,

[image]

We can see that,  for $n=1, X(1)$, we are left with not just a single pulese at $n=1$ but with 4 digital pulses standing at n=1,n=2,n=3. I.e., simply substituting n=1 produces 4 pulses! in the answer. I would argue that even multiplying with $1$ (in an effort to trim amplitude) would not decrease the amplitudes of the extra pulses at n=0,n=2 and n=3 which we should get rid of. Considering this, I did write an interpretation that interprets $x(n)$ better. My own representation is:

$x(n) = n[u(n) - u(n-1)]$

If we use my estimation for $X(n)$, for each n, it leaves on a single pulse and scales the same accordingly! Isn't that the correct mathematical interpretation of $X(n)$? It would really help to know where I am mistaken. I apologize for any mistakes in basics I may have presented as I am new to DSP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signal you came up with is identical to zero for all values of $n$:

$$x[n]=n\big(u[n]-u[n-1]\big)=0\tag{1}$$

Note that $u[n]-u[n-1]=\delta[n]$, which is only non-zero for $n=0$. So we have $x[n]=n\delta[n]$, and, consequently, $x[n]=0$ for all values of $n$.

The signal $u[n]-u[n-4]$ equals $1$ for $n\in\{0,1,2,3\}$, and it is zero otherwise. Multiplying this signal with $n$ simply gives the values $n$ in the interval for which $u[n]-u[n-4]$ is non-zero. So your professor is right.